# Deducing vanishing of a cohomology class from pairings

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

Let $M$ be an oriented closed manifold and $G$ a group. Let $x$ be a class in $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$.

Suppose that for every class $y\in H^*(BG,\mathbb{Q})$ and every continuous map
$$f\colon M\to BG,$$
we have that
$$\langle x\cup f^*y,[M]\rangle=0,$$
where $[M]$ is the fundamental class in $H_*(M,\mathbb{Q})$.

**Question:** Does it follow that $x=0$?

*Comment:* I guess it doesn't really matter whether we are working over the rationals or some other ring, or whether $M$ is a manifold, but this is the situation I'm looking at so I've included these details.

Comment: To see that this is false take any manifold $M$ with $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})=0$ and let $G=S^1$. If you want to work with finite groups take $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and assume $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)=0$.

Comment: @Tyrone: I don't understand your comment. If $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ then $H^{n-2}(M; \mathbb{Q}) = 0$.

Comment: @Tyrone: I think your claim that $M$ can be any manifold is false, but maybe the idea you had in mind was the one I mentioned in the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese it doesn't work for, say, a sphere. It works for $\mathbb{H}P^2$, for instance (edit: as I see, now that you also noticed in your answer).

Comment: @Tyrone: The point I was making is that it doesn't work if $\deg x = n-2$. I hope you don't mind that I provided an answer, given that your comment pretty much solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\dim M = n$ and $x$ is a non-zero element of $H^{n-k}(M; \mathbb{Q})$, then you can produce a counterexample if you choose $G$ such that $H^k(BG; \mathbb{Q}) = 0$. For example, you could take $G$ to be finite. Another class of counterexamples can be formed by taking $k = 1$ and $G$ any connected topological group, or $k = 2$ and $G$ any simply connected topological group, or $k = 3$ and $G$ any simply connected Lie group.

There are also counterexamples when $H^k(BG; \mathbb{Q}) \neq 0$.

Let $M = \mathbb{HP}^2$ and let $x$ be a non-zero element of $H^4(M; \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}$. For $G = S^1$, we have $BG = \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$. As $\dim M = 8$, the only way we can have $\langle x\cup f^*y, [M]\rangle \neq 0$ is if $y \in H^4(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Q})$. Note that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ has degree two, so $y = k\alpha^2$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now note that for any map $f : M \to BS^1$, we have $f^*y = f^*(k\alpha^2) = k(f^*\alpha)^2 = 0$ so $\langle x\cup f^*y, [M]\rangle = 0$.

In fact, since $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$, we have $[M, \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}] \cong H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, so every map $f : M \to BS^1$ is nullhomotopic and hence $\langle x\cup f^*y, [M]\rangle = 0$ regardless of what $x$ is.