# Deducing vanishing of a cohomology class from pairings (follow-up)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251683/deducing-vanishing-of-a-cohomology-class-from-pairings). Basically, I would like to know whether the desired vanishing in question can be deduced if we are allowed to vary $G$.

Suppose $M$ is an oriented closed manifold. Fix a class $x\in H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$. Suppose that for *every* group $G$, every class $y\in H^*(BG,\mathbb{Q})$, and every continuous map
$$f\colon M\to BG,$$
we have that
$$\langle x\cup f^*y,[M]\rangle=0,$$
where $[M]$ is the fundamental class in $H_*(M,\mathbb{Q})$.

**Question:** Does it follow that $x=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Suppose for convenience that $M$ is connected.  Then $M$ is equivalent to a classifying space $BG$ for $G$ a topological group equivalent to $\Omega M$.  So we may take $f: M \to BG$ to be the identity map, and if $x \neq 0$, take $y$ to be dual to $x$ under the cup product pairing which is nonsingular.